# How to wrap words in output in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to print specific word character in specific Line (do something like a word wrap)

Suppose I have 40 Character.

**My Name Is Johnty and i am eating an Nut**

and my length for character is 20.

So in First Line I want to Print 20 character but if it will break the word than whole word will print in next line.

For Example , i have 20 character length in first line than don't print like this :

```
First Line : My Name Is Johnty an
Second Line : d i am eating an Nut
```

Instead, I want following output :

```
First Line : My Name Is Johnty
Second Line : and i am eating an 
Third Line : Nut
```

So How to do this in Simple PHP ??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to use the [`wordwrap()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) function of PHP.

Answer (score 2):

**`wordwrap`** — Wraps a string to a given number of characters . [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)

```
<?php
    $text = "My Name Is Johnty and i am eating an Nut";
    $newtext = wordwrap($text, 20, "<br />\n");

    echo $newtext;
    ?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
My Name Is Johnty
and i am eating an
Nut
```

**EDIT 1:**

YES, You can save it in Variable after Split the String. You must be use `explode()`  with inside of `wordwrap()` methods to do this things.

```
      $strText = "My Name Is Johnty and i am eating an Nut"; //here ur string 
         // Wrap lines limited to 20 characters and break
         // them into an array
      $lines = explode("\n", wordwrap($strText, 20, "\n"));
      var_dump($lines);
      $one=$lines;
      print_r($one[0]);
```

**OUTPUT:**

for $one[0],

```
My Name Is Johnty
```

for $one[ 1 ],

```
and i am eating an
```

Comment: Thanks... It Will  Helpful... But can i store the new line in one varible.

Comment: @SachinSanchaniya yes we can do that. Check my `EDIT 1` it will help to you may be fix your requirements

Comment: Thank You.....@LifeTimeProgrammer

Comment: its solve your problems accept any one of answers right @SachinSanchaniya. may help full to future visiters

Answer (score 0):

By using the `wordwrap()` you can wrap the characters within the words.

**Example:**

```
$string = "My Name Is Johnty and i am eating an Nut";
echo wordwrap($string, 20, "<br />\n")
```

**Output:**

```
My Name Is Johnty
and i am eating an
Nut
```

Details about the- [`wordwrap() in http://php.net/`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php).

**Updates:**

```
$string = "My Name Is Johnty and i am eating an Nut";
$arr = explode(PHP_EOL, wordwrap($string, 20, "\n\r"));

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Can i store the new line in one variable... ???

Comment: What do you mean by store?

Comment: i want $first_line = "My Name Is Johnty"   ,  $second_line = "and i am eating an"  , $third_line = "Nut"     ......... Like This... So I can echo $second_line.

Comment: Yes you can do it.

Comment: Updates added to the answer.

Comment: Thank You .... It will helpful for me...